# Can't get img src inside href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't seem to get the img src path from inside an href tag using the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.imagemodal', function() {

    var imgsrc = $('img', this).attr("src");

    alert("IMG: " + imgsrc);

});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="imagemodal"><img src="/images/psmith/5/image.jpg" /></a>
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you closed your anchor link?

Comment: Works fine here, even with the missing `</a>`: http://jsfiddle.net/xhhqU/

Comment: I have...just missed it when I copied the example in

Comment: copied your exact code into jsFiddle and it works. What is your actual code that isn't working?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console section

Answer (score 1):

check this one, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/xhhqU/1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="imagemodal"><img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.imagemodal', function() {
    var imgsrc = $('img', this).attr("src");
    alert("IMG: " + imgsrc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be closing your anchor tag..

```
<a href="#" class="imagemodal"><img src="/images/psmith/5/image.jpg" /></a>
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/s247w/)

Do you get any error in the page in the console section of the browser

Comment: strange...if I use the on event it doesn't work (using jquery 1.7.1) but if I use a straight up click event it works...

Answer (score 0):

What jQuery version do you use?
If it is before 1.7 it does not work. With the later ones it does.

See info taken from jQuery docs page:
"The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers."

Comment: This might be a really good answer if you elaborated on why this might be so.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="imagemodal"><img src="/images/psmith/5/image.jpg" /></a>


$(document).ready(function () {
$('.imagemodal').on('click', function () {           
        var opt_text = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
                    alert(opt_text);               
     })
});
```